# Scala `Set[(K, V)]` indexed by `K`

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections, multimap

Yes, this is basically a `Map[K, V]` with `MultiMap` characteristics **and** no duplicate values of `V` for the same `K`, that makes it a special `MultiMap`.

Is there a collection (in Scala possibly) to properly represent this concept, that can perform fast operation on K? Was the concept already studied and implemented, in case other languages? Mutable? Immutable?

Using `Set[(K, V)]` works but I'm unsure about it performances, especially for things like `.filter(_._1 == x)`. Clearly, a proper lookup would be better. I assume a proper collection would also not allocate all those useless `Pair` instances.

Comment: Note that another possible way to implement a **similar** concept is `Map[K, Set[V]]`, but this allows entries with empty `Set[V]`, that I want to exclude, in addition to a higher overhead.

Comment: You are looking for `com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap<K,V>` from guava. `val hashMultiMap: HashMultimap[K, V] = HashMultimap.create()`

Comment: What about a `Map[K, NonEmptySet[V]]` _(from cats)_? What do you mean with _"higer overhead"_?

Comment: This `NonEmptySet` is interesting, I'll have a look at it and *cats*, but my current project doesn't depend on it so not sure if it's worth. About "higher overhead", for sure managing a `Map[K, Set[V]]` involves more object and references than managing a `Map[K, V]` or `MultiMap[K, V]` ... Ok it's just my assumption but I have that feeling ...

Comment: `HashMultimap[K, V]` seems to model what I need. But it also needs an external library my project doesn't depend on and it's Java. Ok, I can add a conversions.